# Convert ARGB to RGBA using C#

Tags: c#, rgba, argb

I have the following code in C#:

```
Color c;
// Setup ARGB COLOR 80, 20, 86, 20
            c = Color.FromArgb(80, 20, 86, 20);

            int r, g, b, a;

            r = c.R;
            g = c.G;
            b = c.B;
            a = c.A;

            MessageBox.Show("The color in RGBA format is : " +
                            r.ToString() + " " + 
                            g.ToString() + " " + 
                            b.ToString() + " " + 
                            a.ToString());
```

I am attempting to convert the color to RGBA format.  I was thinking that it would just be:

20, 86, 20, 80   <== RGBA ??

But the color does not render the same.  Am I missing something?  Is code needed to convert this?

Thanks Before Hand

Comment: Please post more code and rephrase your question, how are you creating a color from the RGBA format as opposed to the ARGB format?

Comment: Do you need RGBA to create a new Color, or you're trying to get RGBA from the color you created?

Comment: I am trying to create the RGBA color from the ARGB COLOR: 80, 20, 86, 20

Comment: Apparently [not the same](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=RGBA+vs.+ARGB)

Comment: "does not render the same" - *how* are you rendering both the ARGB and RGBA colors?

Comment: Related: [Fast Converting RGBA to ARGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259391/fast-converting-rgba-to-argb)

Comment: crashmstr, the link you provided "Related" I already had seen. But that was of no help.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Do you mean `Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(r,g,b,a)` ?? That wouldn't make any sense.. Not even : `Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(a, r,g,b)` imo.. either you access a Color (ARGB) or a bitmap buffer (BGRA), no use converting I can think of.. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
Color c;
// Setup ARGB COLOR 80, 20, 86, 20
            c = Color.FromArgb(80, 20, 86, 20);

            int r, g, b, a;

            r = c.R;
            g = c.G;
            b = c.B;
            a = c.A;
String rgba = String.Format("rgba({0},{1},{2},{3})", c.R, c.G, c.B, c.A);
```

OR FROM HEX TO RGBA

```
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcolor);
string rgba= String.Format("rgba({0},{1},{2},{3})", col.R, col.G, col.B, c.A);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found no way to do this programatically.  (If anyone knows how please let me know)  I ended up doing a trial and error until I found the correct value.

**FROM ARGB:**
80, 20, 86, 20

**To RGBA:**
20, 86, 20, .3  (Note the .3 is approximate since I am not sure how to calculate the alpha)

Thanks

Comment: This is as little informative as the question. I still don't know the problem neither the solution.

Comment: Apparently you missed my "related" link: [Fast Converting RGBA to ARGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259391/fast-converting-rgba-to-argb)